# prove $abc \ge 8$ for $\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b}+\frac{1}{1+c}=1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I am reading this book about inequalities and the chapter about AM-GM inequalities includes this problem:

Let $a,b,c$ be positive numbers for which  $\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+b}+\frac{1}{1+c}=1$, prove that

$$abc \ge 8$$

The book does not provide full solutions but only hints, and the one for this question is that it is similar to this problem:

Let $a,b,c$ be positive numbers with $a+b+c=1$, prove that

$$(\frac{1}{a}-1)(\frac{1}{b}-1)(\frac{1}{c}-1) \ge 8$$

again there's no solution provided but what I came up with is the following (you can correct me if it is wrong):

$$a+b=1-c$$
$$a+c=1-b$$
$$b+c=1-a$$

$$(\frac{1}{a}-1)(\frac{1}{b}-1)(\frac{1}{c}-1)=(\frac{1-a}{a})(\frac{1-b}{b})(\frac{1-c}{c})=(\frac{b+c}{a})(\frac{a+c}{b})(\frac{a+b}{c})=(\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a})(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{b})(\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c})$$

By AM-GM we have for each term:

$$(\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a}) \ge 2\sqrt{\frac{bc}{a^2}}$$
$$(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{b}) \ge 2\sqrt{\frac{ac}{b^2}}$$
$$(\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c}) \ge 2\sqrt{\frac{ab}{c^2}}$$

By multiplying the three inequalities we have

$$(\frac{b}{a}+\frac{c}{a})(\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{b})(\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c}) \ge 8 \sqrt{\frac{a^2b^2c^2}{a^2b^2c^2}}=8$$

as desired.

Can someone please provide me a proof for the first problem as I cannot find any way around it, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define

\begin{align*}
x&=\frac{1}{1+a}\\
y&=\frac{1}{1+b}\\
z&=\frac{1}{1+c}
\end{align*}

Then your problem transforms into: given $x+y+z=1$ prove $(\frac{1}{x}-1)(\frac{1}{y}-1)(\frac{1}{z}-1) \geq 8$. I believe you know the rest.

Comment: Can you please expand

Answer (score 0):

If the problem states that a, b, and c are positive *integers*, this is pretty easy.  Find a common denominator on the LHS, multiply both sides by the denominator and simplify.  Then you get: $$3+2(a+b+c)+ab+ac+bc=1+(a+b+c)+ab+ac+bc+abc$$  Simplify this and you get $$2+a+b+c=abc$$  The lowest possible non-zero integers are 1, 2, and 3, therefore the lowest value abc can have is 8.

If, however, a, b, and c are the lowest possible real numbers, this is a very different problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the condition by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\prod\limits_{cyc}\frac{a}{1+a}=\prod\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{1+b}+\frac{1}{1+c}\right)\geq\prod\limits_{cyc}\frac{2}{\sqrt{(1+b)(1+c)}}=8\prod\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{1+a}$$
Id est, $abc\geq8$.